# модификатор final у поля блокирует вызов static блока

Tags: java

имеем код

```
class Test{
    public static int x = 1;  

    static {
        System.out.println("static");
    }

}

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Test.x);
    }
}
```

как и ожидается вывод

```
static  
1
```

но если добавить к полю final

```
public static final int x = 1;
```

статик блок не отработает, и выведет `1` .
с чем это связано?

Comment: @ArchDemon
 а ещё в тестовом примере нарушена конвенция стиля кодирования, в частности использование односимвольных имен переменных, константа в нижнем регистре, отсутствует название пакета, имя класса не информативно.

Comment: В общем я не знаю как это описать технически, но немного поиспользовав примеры , предположу что глобал файнал хранится вне класса, или как то отделен от него, поэтому инициализация класса не происходит. Если добавить скажем, ещё одну static переменную, и обратиться к ней то блок static срабатывает как и положено.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static final int` - это [константное выражение времени компиляции](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) (англ. compile time constant expression).

Это означает, что во время компиляции вашего класса `Solution` компилятор берет константу из класса `Test` и прямо использует ее в `Solution` (и в скомпилированном классе `Solution` нет ссылки на класс `Test`). То есть при запуске класса `Solution` загрузка класса `Test` не происходит, а значит не происходит выполнение статических блоков.