# Задачка из OCA по Java

Tags: java, ооп

Упрощенный вид одной из задачи: Что будет выведено на экран?

```
    public class NewClass  {

    static int i;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new NewClass().method());
    }

    public int method(){
        int a;
        if(i < 10) a = 5;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Как я сказал выше - задача упрощенная, но смысл в ней тот же. В исходной задаче для размыливания взгляда в метод передаются различные параметры и прочее.

Конечно же этот код не компилируется. "Есть не нулевая вероятность того, что статическая переменная i будет больше 10 и тогда локальная переменная "а" никогда не будет проиницилизирована". Естественно нам то понятно, что i всегда будет 0. Но а вдруг другой поток захочет ее изменить?
Как можно решить эту задачу? Правильно, сделать i финальной. Давайте сделаем.

```
    public class NewClass  {

    final static int i;
    static{
        i = 0;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new NewClass().method());
    }

    public int method(){
        int a;
        if(i < 10) a = 5;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Бам! Код все равно не компилируется! Хотя, если проиницилизровать финальную переменную в строке ее объявления всё проходит. Вот и прошу объяснить этот момент. Почему код не компилируется.

Объясню свою логику и прошу поправить если не прав: для вызова метода method() нам нужен инстанс класса. По спецификации Java (12.4.1), класс будет загружен в память в одном из 5 случаев (один из случаев - создание объекта). Т.е. статический блок выполнится в 100% случаев и соответственно будет проиницилизирована переменная i.
Но как было сказано выше, код не компилируется. И я где-то не прав... Прошу знатоков объяснить!

Comment: Оставлю для будущих поколений - задал такой же вопрос одному знающему и сертифицированному человеку. Вот его ответ:
Хитрость притаилась именно в блоке статической инициализации. Как Вы сами подметили, если его убрать, а финально-статическое поле проинициализировать в лоб (напр., final static int i = 1;), то все заработает.

Это связано с тем, что блоки инициализации не ограничены в своем поведении: они могут --- причем это типичная ситуация --- могут обращаться к объектам других классов, которые, в свою очередь, могут обратиться к конструкторам / методам нашего подопытного класса.

Comment: Продолжение
 И тогда произойдет дикость: блок инициализации --- я обычно называю его "инитер", чтобы было покороче, --- так вот, инитер еще не отстрелялся до конца, а уже надо исполнять некий метод, где может быть зайствована наша умная переменная. Которая находится еще в дефолтном состоянии. А если она еще и локальная, то компилятор вскинет красный флажок.

Answer (score 0):

Хоть вопрос был задан давно, да и вы сами, в принципе, на него ответили, хотелось бы привести некоторые последовательные и несложные рассуждения.

Чтобы блок `if` выполнился и переменная `a` была проинициализирована, мы должны гарантировать, что к моменту вызова метода `method()` статическая переменная `i` будет иметь значение меньше 10-ти.

В случае

```
static int i;
```

этого не достигается. Ведь хоть при загрузке класса в память переменная `i` и инициализируется нулём, но не факт, что до вызова метода `method()` не вызовется какой-нибудь другой метод, который может изменить `i`, сделав её, например, равной 11.

Чтобы гарантировать неизменяемость `i`, мы можем сделать её `final`. Однако полагаясь на её инициализацию в статическом блоке

```
static final int i;
static {
    i = 0;
}
```

ситуацию мы не улучшаем, ведь, как вы правильно сказали в комментариях, в статических блоках инициализации может быть сделано всё что угодно. В том числе может быть вызван наш метод `method()`, в то время как `i` пока что, опять же, будет не инициализирована.

И наконец запись

```
static final int i = 0;
```

позволяет коду запуститься. Мы сразу же на месте присваиваем `i` значение, и больше она никоим образом измениться не может. Поэтому всяких теоретически небезопасных случаев развития кода не будет и код сможет запуститься.

Если говорить правильнее, то `static final`-переменные (проинициализированные сразу, а не в статическом блоке) - это константные выражения времени компиляции. Если из другого класса обращаться к таким переменным, то загрузка класса, содержащего их, в память осуществляться вообще не будет. Такое явление было разобрано в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1359442/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-final-%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-static-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0) вопросе.